# How to cleanly install Meteor on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

According to https://www.meteor.com/install, the proper way to install Meteor on any Linux system is to run.

`curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`

I am not very enthusiastic about executing in bash something that was just downloaded over Internet (even over HTTPS).

Does anyone know a better way to install Meteor? Isn't it packaged somewhere as a deb or a snap?

Comment: I can't seem to find it in a deb or snap package. You can review the script prior to running it by downloading it directly from [here](https://install.meteor.com/) if that adds to your comfort level.

Comment: Since Meteor's MIT License is compatible with Debian and Ubuntu, I suppose that means the Meteor user base --despite their flashy website-- is currently too small or too shallow to be worth packaging. It just takes one enthusiast and one afternoon to add a package to Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: As suggested by Elder Geek, I looked at the bash install script.

For a clean install on x86_64, it basically:
* Downloads https://meteorinstall-4168.kxcdn.com/packages-bootstrap/1.4.3.1/meteor-bootstrap-x86_64.tar.gz
* Ungzips it to a new temporary dir under $HOME
* Moves the temp dir to $HOME/meteor
* Removes the package that was downloaded earlier
* Creates a launcher called meteor in /usr/local/bin using sudo.

So nothing too surprising, but very annoying that this couldn't be a deb package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the download in steps

```
curl -o new_meteor  https://install.meteor.com/  # output to file new_meteor

bash  ./new_meteor  #  examine this file prior to executing it here
```

you will notice that curl command is just downloading a meteor download manager script `new_meteor`  ... then execute `new_meteor`  using that bash command to perform the actual install ... here is output

```
bash ./download_meteor


Downloading Meteor distribution
######################################################################## 100.0%

Meteor 1.5.1 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your convenience.
This may prompt for your password.

To get started fast:

  $ meteor create ~/my_cool_app
  $ cd ~/my_cool_app
  $ meteor

Or see the docs at:

  docs.meteor.com
```